# bootstrap 2 dropdown not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here i'm using boostrap2 dropdown i don't know what's wrong in this. dropdown menu not working

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Location
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: a jsfiddle or a demo would be useful.

Comment: Just wondering, but why are you using BS2 and not 3 or even 4?

Comment: this is an update from the client which was done earlier

Answer (score 0):

use this link for your answer and check there what error 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h